# CSS page-break with BIXOLON SRP-350II printer

Tags: css, printing

I want to print a document. This document is a bill from my web-based application for a restaurant. This document has two versions.

I use page-break for printing this document. I want to print it on two split pages. This printer has a cutter. But it prints my whole document just in one page.

I want print versions of this bill in two pages with cutter between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On web we send request of one page to printer and default settings of Bixolon do not allow to cut. So follow there steps to allow Bixolon to cut for page

1. Go to printer settings.
2. Open `Printing Preferences`.
3. Choose `Document Settings` tab.
4. on `Paper Cut` section, choose `Page / Job : Partial Cut / Partial Cut`

[image: Bixolon srp-f312ii printing preferences]

Answer (score 1):

you can 
-enter the printer properties 
-click on printing defaults
-choose tap document settings
- on paper cut section select the option " Page / Job :Partial Cut / Partial Cut "
these mainly on windows i haven't seen it on another OS .

Answer (score 0):

if i really understand what you mean you can use some DIV tags to solve your problem
and this is a example of how you can use it:

```
<html>
  <body>

   <!--
     ...
     Here Some Elements for first bill page
     ...
   -->

   <div class="pageBreak"></div>

   <!--
     ...
     And Here Some Elements for next bill page
     ...
   -->

  </body>
</html>
```

and Defining what .pageBreak really is:

```
@media all
{
     .pageBreak { display: none; }
}

@media print
{
     .pageBreak {
          display: block;
          page-break-before: always;

          /* ----- and add more propertys to Cutter Styling -------- */
     }
}
```

Good Luck Friend ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer but this printer cut paper when sent to that 2 order for print . how can send 2 print order to printer in one page ?

Answer (score 0):

Make two separated iframes. Then use javascript to print them separately.

```
iframe1.print();
iframe2.print();
```

Comment: Yes. You're right. But cutting action is out of control via javascript. As I know Bixolon Printers use some characters as cutting sign. And the document when printing is no longer just a plain text.